# Setting allowed ciphers in Orion Application Server

Tags: security, ssl, web-applications

Our company currently hosts a web application for a customer which runs on Orion Application Server. Unfortunately, support for OAS stopped about 10 years ago after Oracle acquired the source code and turned it into OC4J, as such there is very little documentation available, other than it's Wikipedia page.

The issue I am having is now that Chrome/Firefox/Opera are actively blocking insecure SSL connections, the site is inaccessible (Chrome gives the error: Server has a weak, ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key).

I believe to fix this issue, I need to specify a list of acceptable ciphers that the server is allowed to use, but with no documentation available, I have no idea how/where to set this (if it is even possible).

Has anyone else had this issue and been able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out updating to Java 8 resolved this issue for me; after the update, the server started using TLS 1.2 (though I couldn't work out which exact cipher it was using) and the website is now working in Chrome 45.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that the server was previously using Java 6.